# Number and string concatenation in Perl

Tags: perl, concatenation

I am new to Perl. I want to concatenate a string and a number with the `.` operator and the first argument will be a number. I can use join, sprintf and simply print them as print number,string. But I tried it with the `.` operator and got the following:

```
$foo = "hello".34 # Gives hello.34
$foo = 34."hello" # Gives an error
$foo = 34.34 # Gives 34.34
$foo = 34.34.34 # Gives """
$foo = "hello".34."hello" # Gives an error
```

I tried them under Perl debugger.

Why doesn't Perl concatenate a number and string with number as first argument while vice versa works fine? Why does 34.34.34 give """ in Perl?

Comment: Are you sure `"hello".34` actually gives `hello.34` (with the full stop)? On the command line (Linux, [Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (Focal Fossa)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases)), `perl -le 'print "hello".34 '` outputs `hello34` (without a full stop).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every now and then, whitespace is significant. `34 . "hello"` is `"34hello"`. `34."hello"` is a parse error because `34.` looks like the beginning of a floating-point number (maybe `34.5`), and then the parser doesn't know what to do when it gets a `"` instead of another digit. Your code will look better anyway if you use spaces around the dot operator, but following a number it's *required*.

`34.34.34` is a special construct called a [version string](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings) or "v-string" that occurs when you have a number with multiple dots in it, optionally preceded by a `v`. It creates a string where each character *number* comes from the numbers in the v-string. So `34.34.34` is equal to `chr(34) . chr(34) . chr(34)`, and since `chr(34)` is a double-quote, that's the same as `'"""'`. V-strings are useful because they compare the way that version numbers are expected to. Numerically, `5.10 < 5.9`, but as versions, `5.10.0 gt 5.9.0`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How could I find the answer next time myself. Is it available in the documentation? It would be helpful for me. @hobbs

Comment: @Wordzilla read as much of the perldocs as you can, especially `perlsyn`, `perldata` and `perlop` for this stuff :)

Comment: Thanks @hobbs I guess its not available in the Perlop . It shows it as a binary operator for concatenation and doesn't deal with this case. The exact source or citation to your answer in the doc will be very helpful.

Comment: Actually this ambiguity is not really touched on much in the documentation. In `perltrap` there is a reference to the potential for confusion between the `.` character's concatenation and numeric roles, but it doesn't refer to the OP's specific situation, nor how it could be ameliorated with whitespace.

Answer (score 8):

Excellent question. The `.` character has multiple meanings:

1. It's the concatenation operator

   ```
   my $x = 34;
   my $y = 34;
   say $x.$y; # 3434
   ```
2. It's the decimal separator in floating-point numeric literals:

   ```
   3434 / 100 == 34.34
   ```

   Note that the decimal separator must immediately follow the integral part, or it's interpreted as concatenation: `34 .34 == 3434`
3. It's the separator in v-strings (where “v” usually stands for version). In a v-string, each character is separated by a period, and is optionally prefixed by a `v`:

   ```
   34.34.34 eq v34.34.34
   ```

   Each number is translated to the corresponding character, e.g. `64.64.64 eq "@@@"`.

Comment: Thank you @amon for the answer. How can I find the answer myself. Is it found in doc? I have Programming Perl now. It would be very helpful if you provide me the source or link in your answer.

Comment: @Wordzilla hobbs has posted the names of the manpages as a comment under his answer, you can also read them online at http://perldoc.perl.org/ (just type the name of the page into the search field).